# Why does nextjs throw a Hydration error when passing JSON data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, tailwind-css

im trying to implement a simple database browsing interface on my website using nextjs. Though when I add data to the lower leveled containers, it throws a Hydration Error. I have tried looking at the documentation and other SO Threads though none have seemed to help ...

browse.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import Browser from '../components/browser/Browser'
import Linkspace from '../components/Linkspace'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'

function browse() {

return (
<div className='bg-navy-sierra-100 dark:bg-darknavy-900'>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="h-screen">
        <Linkspace/>
        <Browser items='[{"id": "1","title": "this is","vort": "Kharak"},{"id": "2","title": "a test","vort": "Taiidan"},{"id": "4","title": "dont use","vort": "Hiigara"},{"id": "3","title": "in production","vort": "Balcora"}]'/>
    </div>
</div>
)
}

export default browse
```

Browser.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import BrowserContainer from '../videoContainers/BrowserContainer.jsx';

function Browser(items) {

    const data = JSON.parse(items.items)
    const array = []

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        array.push(data[i])
    }

    return (
        <div className='mx-20 flex flex-col gap-4'>
            {array.map((item) => 
                <BrowserContainer trackData={JSON.stringify(item)}/>)
            }
        </div>)
}

export default Browser
```

BrowserContainer.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

function BrowserContainer(trackData) {
    
    const data = JSON.parse(trackData.trackData)

    return (
        <div className="text-navy-sierra-100 bg-darknavy-800" >
            <table>
                <td className='w-16'>{data.id}</td>
                <td className='w-32'>{data.title}</td>
                <td className='w-32'>{data.vort}</td>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BrowserContainer
```

Through some testing and commenting out certain code parts I've found out that the table throws the Hydration error. Though with all the explanations I've read on the Internet, I can't figure out why this is thrown and can't seem to fix it either.

```
<table>
    <td className='w-16'>{data.id}</td>
    <td className='w-32'>{data.title}</td>
    <td className='w-32'>{data.vort}</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Try adding `<tbody>` and  `<tr>` tags to your table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73890509/why-i-use-tr-tag-in-next-js-is-not-working/

Comment: Thank you all, the <tbody> tag fixed the issue for me!