# Why is using a table in Next.js throwing a hydration error?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, html-table

In this code, I have a problem on using  tag. when I use tr tag the error occurs.It says that **Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'


const port = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ml-14">
      <div className="profile">
        <h1 className="mt-5 font-bold">Nasvirat</h1>
        <p className="mt-5">total balance : </p>
      </div>
      <div className="portfolio">
        <h2 className="mt-7">Holding</h2>

        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lois</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default port
```

do u have idea why this happen and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36754) in the `Next.js` repo. The issue is coming from the fact that you do not have `<tbody>` or `<thead>` wrapping your rows.

Although they are not specified to [mandatory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#:%7E:text=The%20element%20is%20not,tbody%3E%20element%20as%20a%20child.) for correctly rendering the table, `next.js` somehow cannot identify this.

My assumption is there is a difference in the code that is run on the server and on the client because of this.

Try adding this:

```
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lois</td>
          <td>Griffin</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

It is noteworthy, that browsers add a `tbody` inside the `table` [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490364/why-do-browsers-still-inject-tbody-in-html5). So even if you skip it, it will end up in your DOM code. This is for older HTML versions as mentioned in the answer. Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/tushar8/pen/ExLLKgR?editors=1111) for that. Check the code and compare it with the actual DOM that is rendered.

I am guessing `next.js` does not add the `tbody` by default when generating on server side.
This is what causes the mismatch.